# How to log and export CPU Usage over time?

Tags: command-line, cpu, log

I am currently doing a project at school about sound proofing a PC Case and need a way to log the CPU load, so that I can graph it against sound and temperature of the case. I am very new to using Ubuntu/Linux, but as it is free and friends have said that it is easy to use I decided to try it out. Thanks in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 4):

Just to name 3:

- [atop](http://www.atcomputing.nl/Tools/atop/)
- package [sysstat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/) and the command [sar](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/sar.1.php)
- [mpstat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpstat)