# Like "PerfMon" in Windows do we have something similar in Ubuntu?

Tags: performance, disk-usage, cpu-load, memory-usage

If I want to capture performance log of a Ubuntu (or any other Linux Distro) Server/Workstation for a period of time, how would I do that?

In Windows, I use something called PERFMON.MSC (LOGMAN.EXE), but not sure about Linux.

I want to run it in background during production hours on everyday from Monday to Friday and as per usage, I will decide allocation of resources.

I would like to monitor following counters:

LOGICAL DISK, PHISICAL DISK, MEMORY, NETWORK INTERFACE, SWAP USAGE, PROCESSES, PROCESSOR, SYSTEM.

How it would be possible to get a graphical view as well. it would be best if I can get in on html pages. thus I can represent the same to my clients if needed.

(

In case of command line, please provide me the command and the way to extract it view/analyze the log data.

Just give to a idea; I use following command line in Windows computers:

"Logman.exe create counter PerfMon.1Min -o "C:\PerfLogs\PerfMon.1Min.blg" -f bincirc -v mmddhhmm -max 512 -c "\Memory*" "\Network Interface(*)*" "\Paging File(*)*" "\PhysicalDisk(*)*" "\Processor(*)*" "\Process(*)*" "\Server*" "\System*" -si 00:01:00"

"Logman.exe start PerfMon.1Min"

)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to add I would like to monitor:

LOGICAL DISK,

PHISICAL DISK,

MEMORY,

NETWORK INTERFACE,

SWAP USAGE,

PROCESSES,

PROCESSOR,

SYSTEM,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Glances ?
Refer this link, it has some thing in common.

[System Monitoring Tools For Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293426/system-monitoring-tools-for-ubuntu)

Best of luck !!

Answer (score 2):

Sysstat is your friend, assuming you are fine with using the command line. Have a look for examples [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267715/how-to-log-memory-usage-per-minute-on-ubuntu-server/267718#267718) for memory usage, and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346168/how-to-log-and-export-cpu-usage-over-time/346176#346176) for cpu usage.

Comment: thank you. however how it would be possible to get a graphical view as well. it would be best if i can get in on html pages. thus i can represent the same to my clients as well.

Comment: Sysstat can log to XML as far as I know, then you just have to write a small script to translate to html.

Answer (score 1):

`top` has a batch mode (`-b`) that generates output without the screen control codes.  By adding some other switches and options, you may be able to focus in on the stats you need and redirect it to a file or other program for processing.